# Hive and Tableau - Proxies/ODBC?

Tags: proxy, tableau-api

So, I have a Hive server (Cloudera, Thrift via HTTP) set up and working, and can connect to it from Tableau using the ODBC driver for Cloudera Hive - all good, from the servers in the AWS farm.

However, no luck from the client site/their end-user PCs.

The reason for this is that they require all outbound traffic to the internet (here, my AWS instance) to go through proxies using NTLM, and I can't get the Cloudera ODBC driver to talk via the NTLM proxy. It appears to ignore the Windows proxy settings entirely, in fact.

I'm aware of two (obvious) solutions - use Fiddler/cntlm locally on the box as a reverse proxy / set up a reverse-proxy in the customer's net and point ODBC at that - both of these are somewhat unpalatable to the users.

So: Is there a way to get Cloudera's ODBC driver (or Windows itself) to forcibly go via an NTLM proxy without requiring additional software/servers? Or is there a Cloudera-Hive-compatible Tableau connector that works well with proxies in the middle?

TL;DR: Need to get from Tableau client on Windows to Cloudera Hive in AWS across an NTLM proxy. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The Cloudera Hive ODBC driver currently doesn't support proxy and NTLM authentication. If this feature is important for you I would suggest raising it as a feature request against Cloudera. I am not aware of any other Hive ODBC driver that supports proxy and NTLM.

Holman